# Limit access to a pipe to a process (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

Is it possible to limit access to a named pipe by process (either image name, or process ID would work)?

The context here is a Filter Minidriver which has to communicate with a user-space service that would do most of the business logic. Since this communication is security-sensitive, I'd like to protect it from external interference, while by default it seems the named pipe, created by the driver can be communicated with by *any* user-space process that knows the name of the pipe (which is trivial to discover by static or dynamic analysis).

This is what I already know: Pipes are securable objects in Windows, and as such, they have a security descriptor. This security descriptor can contain a DACL, which is supposed to limit access to the object. I have searched extensively for documentation and examples of conditional ACEs, which I hoped could do what I want, but I failed to find anything related.

**EDIT**: I have accepted MSalters' answer. It is generally accepted that `SYSTEM` == `ring0` and while code signing of drivers may seem like it matters, `SYSTEM` can disable code signing easily, so there is no need for privilege escalation from `SYSTEM` to `ring0` - they're already the same. On the other hand, even the default security descriptor (in the minifilter driver context - see `FltBuildDefaultSecurityDescriptor`) contains a restriction so that only `SYSTEM` and Administrators can access the object, so no further action is necessary (or possible, it seems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image names are not secured anyway, anyone can create a "Notepad.EXE". And a process ID is just a number and can be reused, so that's no protection either. Besides, there are many ways in which you can smuggle a DLL inside another process, so even if you knew that a particular process was running your EXE, you still wouldn't know if it was running *just* your EXE.

The Windows security model uses the notion of security principals (user and system accounts). Those are directly supported by ACL's, and those are protected against spoofing. It makes sense if your filter driver refuses to talk to just anyone, but it's willing to talk to process A of user X, it should be willing to talk to any process of user X.

Comment: I understand that this is the Windows security model, *however* the full image name (along with the path) is reliable for me, since there is a filter driver involved, which can monitor that the service binary file is not modifier. Furthermore, due to the high security significance of the communication between the two parties, if I don't secure this pipe, it will indirectly allow escalation from SYSTEM to ring0, which is NOT acceptable in my case. Of course, I welcome any criticism of my "security model" and assumptions.

Comment: Also I should add that there are other security measures planned, for example asking the human user to review which Windows users can debug the process and so on, which are meant to further limit other attack vectors, similar to the one you pointed out.

Comment: I don't get how a filter driver (at individual device level) would establish that a certain complete path (which is generally system-wide) is reliable. Even if the file itself isn't changed on disk, you'd have to make sure that the full path doesn't refer to another device altogether. And while you may think C:\ is your hard disk, with reparse points and the like it's not that simple.

Comment: As for "escalation from SYSTEM to ring 0", I'm going to channel Raymond Chen: once you've gained control of SYSTEM, you have gained control of the system. As SYSTEM you can already load another driver, which means SYSTEM has access to ring 0 regardless of what you do in your driver.

Comment: You are correct. I just realized you can enable unsigned drivers when you are SYSTEM and from there on run any code you want as ring0. I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: Finally, asking a "human user" to verify there are no other accounts with debug permission is missing the point as well. If another account has that right, it has the ability to hide that right.  Remember, you're modeling threat vectors. You can't assume your opponent is making it easy for you.